# What distribution to use for response variable which is a ratio of counts (that are not independent) where it can be >1?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, count-data, ratio, ecology, observational-study

I have two sets of counts, bat passes and feeding buzzes. A feeding buzz is not independent of a bat pass. In a single bat pass, there can be multiple feeding buzzes. My response variable is buzz ratio, number of feeding buzzes per bat pass  so the ratio ranges from 0 to >1.

I have a light treatment (On, Control) that is my explanatory variable. What would be an appropriate test/model?

Someone suggested

```r
mod <- glm(cbind(FeedingBuzz, BatPass) ~ Light, family=binomial)
```

Would this work in my case? And if so, how should I account for overdispersion (if any?)

Comment: Does the treatment alter both buzzes and passes or only one? Do you care about the mechanism (if treatment lifts one and lowers the other)?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand "bat pass" and "feeding buss" so will call the counts $X$ and $Y$, and then your ratio variable is $X/(X+Y)$.  So $X$ and $Y$ are not counting the same events.  Your proposal of modelling the pair $(X,Y)$ with a binomial model using `glm` is sound.  Assuming that $X$ and $Y$ have independent Poisson distributions, the conditional distribution of $X$ given $X+ Y=n$ is binomial, and having samples of X and Y, you can test the Poisson assumption.

If the Poisson assumption do not hold (and that is quite possible, especially if counts are large), then you can still use the binomial as a working model, with corrections for overdispersion. In R you can do that via the quasibinomial family!  The code will look like

```r
mod  <-  glm( cbind(Feedingbuzz, Batpass) ~ 
              Light, family = quasibinomial)
```

Comment: Okay thanks! So I have counts X and Y and my response variable is Y/X. So just to confirm, it is fine if my response variable is not between 0 and 1 when using a binomial distribution?

Comment: You should explain the practkcal setup better, maybe i did not understand. Logistic regression needs oroportions j3tween zero and one

Comment: Okay let me give an example! 
I am counting the number of times a person is walking past me (X). I am also counting the number of times they clap their hands as they walk past (Y). 
My response variable is the number of times they clap their hands for each time they walk past (Y/X).
And I have a treatment (On and off).

Comment: Forgot to mention that I only know the total times a person walks past me and the total number of times they clap their hands as they walk past (in a minute). But I don't know for each individual pass of X, how many Y there are as this was not recorded, only the total.

Comment: For such a situation I guess you could use a poisson regression for "number of clapps" with an offset "log of times person walking past me"

Comment: How well would it work to model claps as a flexible nonlinear function of the covariate times walking past me?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that treatment can change both the numerator and the denominator of the rate (not ratio), you can use Seemingly Unrelated Estimation with two Poisson models. This will allow you to calculate the change in the rate from treatment but also see how the numerator and denominator respond to treatment individually. It seems that would be likely since bats like the dark, so they might come out less frequently when it's bright but then feast more since the light attracts insects. But I am not a biologist, though I did trap some bats in college for one. You see a similar phenomenon with expenditure on vacations, where people with kids are less likely to go on one but spend more conditional on taking a trip. This does weird things to the expenditure per vacation rate.

I will model how the rate of physician office visits to non-physician office visits changes with having private medical insurance in the US. The model is restricted to people with at least one non-physician office visit.

Here's the annotated output from Stata:

```
. // data prep
. use "https://github.com/zhangyl334/bivpoisson/raw/main/Health_Data.dta", clear

. gen rate = ofp/ofnp
(146 missing values generated)

. drop if missing(rate)
(146 observations deleted)

. sum rate ofnp ofp

    Variable |        Obs        Mean    Std. dev.       Min        Max
-------------+---------------------------------------------------------
       rate |         61    3.714508     4.13267          0         17
        ofnp |         61    4.016393    4.540528          1         25
         ofp |         61    6.868852    5.358717          0         23

. 
. // fit individual poisson models
. poisson ofp i.privins, nolog // physician office visits

Poisson regression                                      Number of obs =     61
                                                        LR chi2(1)    =   5.13
                                                        Prob > chi2   = 0.0236
Log likelihood = -224.99292                             Pseudo R2     = 0.0113

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
         ofp | Coefficient  Std. err.      z    P>|z|     [95% conf. interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
   1.privins |   .3838089   .1789111     2.15   0.032     .0331497    .7344681
       _cons |    1.58045   .1714986     9.22   0.000     1.244319    1.916581
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

. estimates store n

. poisson ofnp i.privins, nolog // non-physician office visits

Poisson regression                                      Number of obs =     61
                                                        LR chi2(1)    =   8.16
                                                        Prob > chi2   = 0.0043
Log likelihood = -198.34391                             Pseudo R2     = 0.0202

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        ofnp | Coefficient  Std. err.      z    P>|z|     [95% conf. interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
   1.privins |   .6869552   .2664854     2.58   0.010     .1646533    1.209257
       _cons |   .7621401   .2581989     2.95   0.003     .2560795    1.268201
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

. estimates store d

. 
. // combine the estimation results and het-robustify variance
. suest n d, vce(robust)

Simultaneous results for n, d                               Number of obs = 61

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |               Robust
             | Coefficient  std. err.      z    P>|z|     [95% conf. interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
n_ofp        |
   1.privins |   .3838089   .3395793     1.13   0.258    -.2817543    1.049372
       _cons |    1.58045   .3233129     4.89   0.000     .9467688    2.214132
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
d_ofnp       |
   1.privins |   .6869552   .5196715     1.32   0.186    -.3315822    1.705493
       _cons |   .7621401   .4978685     1.53   0.126    -.2136642    1.737944
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

. // calculate the predicted number of visits with and without insurance
. margins privins, expression(exp(predict(equation(n_ofp))))
warning: cannot perform check for estimable functions.

Adjusted predictions                                        Number of obs = 61
Model VCE: Robust

Expression: exp(predict(equation(n_ofp)))

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |            Delta-method
             |     Margin   std. err.      z    P>|z|     [95% conf. interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
     privins |
          0  |   4.857143   1.570377     3.09   0.002     1.779261    7.935025
          1  |    7.12963   .7403458     9.63   0.000     5.678579    8.580681
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

. margins privins, expression(exp(predict(equation(d_ofnp))))
warning: cannot perform check for estimable functions.

Adjusted predictions                                        Number of obs = 61
Model VCE: Robust

Expression: exp(predict(equation(d_ofnp)))

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |            Delta-method
             |     Margin   std. err.      z    P>|z|     [95% conf. interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
     privins |
          0  |   2.142857   1.066861     2.01   0.045      .051848    4.233866
          1  |   4.259259   .6344072     6.71   0.000     3.015844    5.502675
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

. // calculate rates with insurance and without
. margins privins, expression(exp(predict(equation(n_ofp)))/exp(predict(equation(d_ofnp))))
warning: cannot perform check for estimable functions.

Adjusted predictions                                        Number of obs = 61
Model VCE: Robust

Expression: exp(predict(equation(n_ofp)))/exp(predict(equation(d_ofnp)))

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |            Delta-method
             |     Margin   std. err.      z    P>|z|     [95% conf. interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
     privins |
          0  |   2.266667   1.454272     1.56   0.119    -.5836545    5.116988
          1  |   1.673913    .301898     5.54   0.000     1.082204    2.265622
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

. // difference the rates to get the effect of insurance
. margins ar.privins, expression(exp(predict(equation(n_ofp)))/exp(predict(equation(d_ofnp)))) post
warning: cannot perform check for estimable functions.

Contrasts of adjusted predictions                           Number of obs = 61
Model VCE: Robust

Expression: exp(predict(equation(n_ofp)))/exp(predict(equation(d_ofnp)))

------------------------------------------------
             |         df        chi2     P>chi2
-------------+----------------------------------
     privins |          1        0.16     0.6898
------------------------------------------------

--------------------------------------------------------------
             |            Delta-method
             |   Contrast   std. err.     [95% conf. interval]
-------------+------------------------------------------------
     privins |
   (1 vs 0)  |  -.5927536   1.485278     -3.503845    2.318337
--------------------------------------------------------------

. estimates store sup
```

Here are the expected visits since $\mathbf{E}[y \vert x ] = \exp \{\alpha + \beta \cdot x \}$:

1. People with insurance have $\exp(1.58045  + .3838089)=7.12963$ doc visits
2. People with insurance have $\exp(.6869552+.7621401) = 4.2592594$ non-physician visits.
3. People without insurance have $\exp(1.58045) = 4.857141$ doc visits
4. People with insurance have $\exp(.7621401) = 2.1428572$ non-physician visits.

This means that the difference in the rate is
$$\frac{7.12963}{4.2592594}  - \frac{4.857143}{2.1428572} = 1.6739131 - 2.2666667= -.5927536$$

This means that people without insurance seek professional medical help less frequently, especially from non-physicians, since they bear the full cost. This makes sense if they only go to the office when they are pretty sick, at which point highly-skilled care is needed.